# Is there a portable way to have "SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM T" semantic?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I want to read data in blocks of say 10k records from a database.

I found [Result limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29) on wikipedia and it seems obvious that this can't done with sql in a portable way.

Another approach could be [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) which offers many methods for queries, but how could I decide that enough rows have been read. Through the callbacks like RowMapper and ResultSetExtractor it can't be indicated, that enough data has been read.

EDIT: I was looking for a solution for JdbcTemplate 
This [post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12205) suggests to use [setMaxRows](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.3/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setMaxRows%28int%29) which I had overlooked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Grab [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/) or [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html). Both are familiar with various database dialects and will handle the nasty DB specifics under the hoods transparently.

In Hibernate you can paginate using [`Criteria#setFirstResult()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) and [`Criteria#setMaxResults()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults%28int%29). E.g.

```
List users = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
    .setFirstResult(0) // Index of first row to be retrieved.
    .setMaxResults(10) // Amount of rows to be retrieved.
    .list();
```

In JPA you can do similar using [`Query#setFirstResult()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) and [`Query#setMaxResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29).

```
List users = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.id");
    .setFirstResult(0) // Index of first row to be retrieved.
    .setMaxResults(10) // Amount of rows to be retrieved.
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Actually, rather than having to do the whole mapping thing, you can use the Dialect classes in Hibernate to modify SQL to include a limit.  Dialect defines a getLimitString() method you can use to extract the mechanism for building limits for various DBs

Comment: This is one of the beauties of ORM. In MySql, you can also do this with the LIMIT command.

Answer (score 5):

There is an ANSI standard syntax from [SQL:2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008):

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM TABLE t
 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

...but it's not supported on most databases at this time.

Comment: I can understand why everyone breaks the standard on this.  Why require four keywords when `LIMIT` is enough?

Comment: @dan04: Now that's just plain crazy talk =)

Comment: Hmmm. Another standard way that will be implemented so infrequently as to be off-standard.

Answer (score 4):

There is no portable way of doing that on plain SQL, because different SQL Engines use different syntaxes for that.

Use a Database Abstraction Layer, or DBAL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer

http://jonasbandi.net/wiki/index.php/ORM_Solutions_for_Java

Answer (score 2):

If you want a portable way, you need to move up an abstraction layer, as there's no portable SQL way(not one that databases actually implement anyways) - and use ORM mappers like e.g hibernate.

If you do need raw JDBC, you'll have to write specific SQL for eache specific database - which is often the case anyway as writing 100% portabl SQL is pretty hard in all but the trivial cases.

The last resort is to run the query without any restrictions and just iterate over the 10 first results you get back - though this doesn't leverage the database capabilities and would be quite bad if your query results in *many* rows.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Thats why database abstraction layers like Hibernate contains SQL *dialects* where you choose the one to use with your database.