# Is it possible to do Pagination in JSF (ui:repeat)?

Tags: jsf, pagination

I am trying to do **pagination** in jsf. I am getting my search results in **ui:repeat** from the **JavaBean.**

How can I use **pagination** here ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Can you provide some code?

Comment: [Yes,that has already been solved here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519569/jsf2-paging-pager-for-repeater)