# Pagination in jsf2 in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2

I am creating web application for booking tickets. After querying from DB for given inputs now i have 230 records (ticket informations) which has been added to list ,as objects (pojo's) .in JSF i am using "ui:repeat" to iterate the list. Here got confused how to create pagination on this. (i want to display 40 records /page). I should not hit the backend for each and every "NEXT" or "PREVIOUS" click .. Any help would be thankful.

Note: when i hit search button my flow will  navigate to result.jsf page where i passed the 230 records for display. 
Technology: Spring web flow and JSF 2

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519569/jsf2-paging-pager-for-repeater) could help

Comment: If you don't want to perform ajax requests when next-previous clicking, you'll need to use javascript to hide/show each page. You'll probably need to play with `ui:repeat`'s `varStatus` properties to assign-locate page id's and you'll also need an `h:panelGroup` or a `div` in order to wrap each page's content.

Answer (score -1):

simplest solution is to use [PrimeFaces DataTable Pagination](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf) or equivalent without reinventing the wheel

Comment: Since application is for ticket booking (need to show many records) and requires more customization in UI(front end) to display data. using primeface framework will it be good???.

Comment: I think you MUST use it! IMO PF is the best UI framework (for JSF) out there: has a component for every need, but payback is that you need time to know well each one. Check the showcase to get an idea ;)